# How to avoid callback-hell using asyncio in python

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, python-asyncio, asynccallback

I have the following situation.
I have 3 Services `JobInitiator`,`Mediator`,`Executor` That talk to eachother in the following manner.

- The `JobInitiator` once every X minutes publishes to a queue (RabbitMQ) a requested job
- The `Executor` service every Y minutes sends a REST API call to the `Mediator` service and asks if there is any jobs to be done. If so - the `Mediator` pulls a message from the queue and returns the message to the `Executor` service in the response.
- After the `Executor` finishes executing the job - he posts the job results to an API in the `Mediator` service that publishes it to a queue that the `JobInitiator` listens to.

Side notes + restrictions and limitations:

- The `Mediator` service is just a REST API wrapper to my queue. The main issue is that `Executor` service can't be accessed publicly - only outgoing api calls are allowed.
- I cannot connect the queue directly from the `JobInitiator` to the `Executor` service

Up until now - nothing really special about this process. The thing i was wondering about is if its possible to write this with asyncio in python so i won't deal with callback hell. Something like this (pseudo code)

```
class JobInitiator(object):
    def do_job():
        token = await get_token()
        applicative_results = await get_results(token=token)
```

where `get_token()` and `get_results()` both run through the process described above.

Comment: It's definitely possible to use `await` as you describe, you just need to use asyncio-aware libraries for underlying communication (e.g. [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) for REST calls). Your title seems to be asking _how_ to do so, but that's definitely too broad for the scope of an SO question.

Comment: @user4815162342 - sorry about the partial comment. The issue here is that the job the consumer in the `Mediator` doing is by itself async - so the response consumer in the `JobInitiator` has to distinguish between contexts. Do you know any rabbitmq library that does this async context preservation consumption?

Comment: maybe this will help.  Please let me know if you get it working: https://github.com/pika/pika/tree/stable#pika-provides-the-following-adapters